# AVX2 multiply 2 vectors of 64 bit integers discarding the upper half of each results?

Tags: x86-64, simd, avx, avx2

Can multiplication of 2 64-bit integers be vectorized if only the lower portion of the result is needed?

Comment: @PeterCordes, this is a dup. Isn't it possible with enough rep just to close a question outright rather than wait for 5 votes?

Comment: Dupe-hammer now applied. ;-)

Comment: @Zboson: I don't have a gold badge in any of the tags this started with.  Editing in an `[x86]` wouldn't let me close it.  They wisely based it on rep-in-a-tag, not just overall rep.